# How can execute a block of code with loops into the intern framework

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, intern

I´m using intern framework with selenium, I want to execute a loop which look for elements in the table. The loop find each element and saves them in array, after the  elements will be obtained to do operations later.

The idea is next:

```
browser.wait(2000)            
.then(function () {
    while (true) {
    ifHasElements=browser.isDisplayed("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr["+contRowsTable+"]").end()                    
    if (ifHasElements) {
        console.log("into if")                         
        browser.elementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr["+contRowsTable+"]/td[1]")
        .clickElement()
        .end()                    
        rows[contRowsTab]=browser.elementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr["+contRowsTable+"]")              
        } else {
           break
         }
    contRowsTab++;
    contRowsTable++;                  
    }
})
```

I dont know if I execute a loop and at the same time obtain elements into the then block. Somebody who can help me with this, thanks a lot..

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
var visibleRows = [];
var stopStoring = false;

return browser
    .wait(2000)
    .then(function () {
        return this.parent
            // find all the rows
            .findAllByXpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr')
            .then(function (rows) {
                // store the visible rows until the first non-visible row is encountered
                return rows.reduce(function (chain, row) {
                    return chain.then(function () {
                        return row
                            .isVisible()
                            .then(function (isVisible) {
                                if (!isVisible) {
                                    stopStoring = true;
                                }
                                if (isVisible && !stopStoring) {
                                    visibleRows.push(row);
                                }
                            });
                    });
                }, this.parent);
            })
            .then(function () {
                // for each visible row, click the first td in the row
                return visibleRows.reduce(function (chain, row) {
                    return chain
                        .findByXpath('./td[1]')
                        .click()
                        .end();
                }, this.parent);
            });
    });
```

In this code I'm first finding and storing the first contiguous run of visible rows. Then, for each of those rows, I click the first table cell in the row.